# Waypoint not a function error all of a sudden

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I created a Wordpress theme and it's been working fine for the last year but now all of a sudden I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Waypoint is not a function

I have checked the page source to make sure jQuery and waypoints is loading before my customjs file which calls the function so I'm not sure whats going wrong.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: if you are loading the Waypoint  via CDN then check whether it is still live or not.

Comment: Have you upgraded the version of jQuery you're using?

Comment: Its loading waypoints locally, which i have checked is the latest version. Jquery is coming from Wordpress itself so it should be up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by adding waypoints to my wordpress enqeue command

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'luxi-custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/luxi-custom-js.js', array('waypoints'), '', true );
```